# "Weng" syllables rhyme with the fnal -ong

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

According to Wiedenhof's *A Grammar of Mandarin*, page 44,

> "*Weng*" syllables rhyme with the fnal -ong [ʊŋ]

However, he'd specified *weng* as [wʌŋ], to add

> *Weng* displays the same type of variation as the fnal *-un*: it may lose
>   its rounding toward the end, [wəŋ].

Page 66 reads

> there's free variation between [wʌŋ] and [ʊŋ] for both fnals, with
>   complementary distribution

Can somebody please clarify the apparent ambiguities?

In the second paragraph, what does *end* refer to?

Answer (score 2):

> In the second paragraph, what does end refer to?

When I speak, I tends to do something like this /wʊ-ɤŋ/. I have never noticed this behavior before. For the word 老翁 (old man), if you say it either way: /lɑʊ.wʊŋ/, /lɑʊ.wəŋ/, /lɑʊ.wɤŋ/, /lɑʊ.wʊəŋ/, etc, they are all interpreted as the same word, thus "free variations". This depends on the individual accent.

I have never studied rhymes seriously before, so if your book says "weng" rhymes with "tong", then they must be using the /wʊŋ/ way of speaking. For example: 通風 (air circulation) may be pronounced as /tʊŋ.fʊŋ/ or /tʊŋ.fɤŋ/, but never as /tɤŋ.fɤŋ/. I personally say /tʊŋ.fɤŋ/.

As for your last quote, I don't understand how the free variation has complementary distribution.

Answer (score 0):

`ong`, to me, a Chinese, is more like `o`+`eng` (but pronounced fast so that it sounds like a single vowel `ong`), which rhymes with `eng` of course. There is another explanation that sometimes Mandarin spoken in other places of China (Guangdong etc.) differs from the "real" mandarin, so that in those places, `eng` and `ong` are not differentiated. By the way, I think `eng` is more like [ɘŋ], depending on how I say that vowel every day. I sorry that I cannot answer your second question, as I haven't read the book. I'm not a Chinese linguist, but I hope this solved your issue.